# How to use external API within Yii2 application?

Tags: api, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'd like to use external API within Yii2 application.
I couldn't find any tutorial about it.
I'd like to know how to do it in a decent way - do I have to build separate module to use this API or organize it in another way?
Any simple examples would be appreciated.

I'd like to build a tool, to use external API of other online application. To be straightforward - I'd like to import invoices etc. from external accounting system to my Yii2 application. This accounting system has API and I wonder how to use it properly inside Yii2 application.

The perfect solution for now would be to install ready module like "yii2-accountingsystemname-api", then I put some login and password for this system and I'm good to go - I can use it inside my application like:
`getInvoices->all()` etc.

Comment: I've seen this [open discussion](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/3635) on implementing REST as Client API Service in Yii. You may find useful info as a start for what you are trying to build there.

Comment: there is also this [extention](https://github.com/hiqdev/yii2-hiart) mentioned in that same discussion that seems to be using [guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/) on consuming external API's.

Answer (score 1):

After doing a bit of research I have found this guide that explains how to use third-Party code with the Yii2 application:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-yii-integration.html

This is a excerpt from that article:

> Using Third-Party Libraries in Yii To use a third-party library in a
>   Yii application, you mainly need to make sure the classes in the
>   library are properly included or can be autoloaded.
>
> Using Composer Packages Many third-party libraries are released in
>   terms of Composer packages. You can install such libraries by taking
>   the following two simple steps:
>
> modify the composer.json file of your application and specify which
>   Composer packages you want to install. run composer install to install
>   the specified packages. The classes in the installed Composer packages
>   can be autoloaded using the Composer autoloader. Make sure the entry
>   script of your application contains the following lines to install the
>   Composer autoloader:
>
> ```
> // install Composer autoloader
> require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php');
>
> // include Yii class file
> require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');
> ```

I suggest that you read the article because there is lots of other valuable information that may help you, and possibly better suit your needs than what I copied above.

Best of luck with your project!

Comment: Thanks Trevor.It is useful, I've seen it, but I think it touches third-party ready components.
I was asking and wondering about hot to build a tool, to use external API of other online application. To be straightforward - I'd like to import invoices etc. from external accounting system to my Yii2 application. This accounting system has API and I wonder how to use it properly inside Yii2 application.